# One line each word in a single Text SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, swiftui

This is what I have:

[image]

First square is correct cause the word is longer than the frame so multiline works good...in the last square I'd like to have JUDO MIX like BASKETBALL MIX, on 2 lines, but I don't know what to do because Text is in a ForEach and I can't edit Text frame, otherwise BASKETBALL and other words will be truncated. Any suggestions on how to achieve 1 line each word?

This is my code:

```
ForEach(0 ..< array.count, id: \.self) { index in
    Image(array[index].val)
        .customReflection()
    VStack {
    Text(array[index].category)
         .font(.title)
         .fontWeight(.bold)
         .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
         .frame(width: 181)
    }
}
```

Comment: Get components separated by space and put them in a vstack with 2 Text

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I added code, it's very simple, as you can see I already have the minimum frame, I can't edit it anymore cause it will affect all the text views and I don't want it, I only want to have 2 lines text, 1 line each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Text` to this:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(array[index].category.components(separatedBy: " "), id: \.self) { word in
        Text(word)
    }
}
```

I can't test that solution out at time of writing this, but that should work. It just separates the string by words and puts each on its own line.

Also, instead of `.multilineTextAlignment()`, just set the alignment of the `VStack`

---

Another solution would be to switch out the spaces (" ") in the string with "\n" to make a new line after each word. That would be:

```
Text(array[index].category.components(separatedBy: " ").joined(separator: "\n"))
```